# Copy value from Query to Form or Table (Access)

Tags: database, ms-access, math, ms-access-2010

My question is, how can I simply copy a count result from a query and show it on a table linked to it... Or directly on a form.

There is my example:

```
**TABLE**
-Name-        -Material-        -Quantity-
Pencil        Drawing            X
Eraser        Drawing            X
Cables        Electronics        X
Camera        Photograph         X
```

(The "X" equals to the quantity of same material, in this example is 2-Drawing, 1-Electronics and 1-Photograph)

```
**QUERY**
-Material-    -Material-
 Group By      Count
```

(This query returns the result of the "X", grouped by "Material" and when running it, the column named as "CountMaterialMath")

So what should I do? Make an Expression on my form showing it on a text field (I don't know how to do it), or just copy/call the value someway to the table.

Really thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If i get this right have you checked **DLookup function**?

Place a textbox(txtToShow) on to your form and use this

**txtToShow = DLookup("[YourTable]" , "Query")**

Kind Regards,
KB

Comment: It gives me an error: #NAME?    I just copy txtToShow = DLookup("[tbl_MATERIAL NOVO]" , "cnst_MATERIAL NOVO COUNTER")

Comment: It is because there is mismatch between the name of your textbox control and the name you use in your DLookup // Create a textbox name it txtToShow and then use the function

Comment: Do you think that the problem is on Relations? http://s5.postimg.org/xictqr2mv/Print_Screen_error_2.png

Comment: Create a form with a text field (where you will show your "X"). Name text field =  txtToShow and finally use the function.

Comment: Really sorry man about my ignorance... but It gives me another popup error, maybe the local where I pasted the code: http://postimg.org/image/v2b0cwkk3/

Comment: No problem!  Is cnst_Material Novo Counter a query?

Comment: that gives me this results: http://postimg.org/image/kjb0nqhw3/ where I will show on the form

Comment: I will give a try again and let you know

Comment: okok... Man if you want I can give the database to you, for me no problem

Comment: No problem im setting this up

Comment: I'm really thankful for your help. It will help me lot on my job! I'm owe you one!

Comment: Works fine. Cant find out why is not working for you

Comment: Maybe my relations are not well linked